# Avoiding ImportError: No module named numpy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, installation, numpy

When I try to `import numpy`, I get the following message.

```
>>> import numpy
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from arcpy.toolbox import *
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\toolbox.py", line 342, in <module>
    from management import Graph, GraphTemplate
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 22, in <module>
    import _management
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\_management.py", line 14, in <module>
    import _graph
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\_graph.py", line 27, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Comment: Could you please supply the Python output from the following command: `sys.executable` ?

Comment: have you tried http://mattmakesmaps.com/blog/2013/07/10/fixing-arcgis-10-dot-1-python-console-numpy-import-error/

Comment: @radouxju This has worked. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: To make your error message available to future searches would you be able to edit your question to copy/paste its text rather than just a picture, please?

Comment: @PolyGeo sorry, I can;t copy and paste it. Now that it is working, the error doesn't appear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have purposed @radouxju comment referencing [THIS](http://mattmakesmaps.com/blog/2013/07/10/fixing-arcgis-10-dot-1-python-console-numpy-import-error/) link as the answer to this question for future viewers:

"One solution to this is to explicitly append the PYTHONPATH environment variable to reference the ArcGIS10.1 Python install’s site-packages directory."

[image]

Comment: Just to let others know. If you install this in 2015 your packages, particularly if you use anaconda install rather than pip install might be installed under users in windows. You need to add that path to the environment and not the one proposed above.

Comment: FYI: Pointing to your python27 site-packages when python3 is the default location will break things.